# Time dependent pie chart

Tags: visualization

I am looking for the name of a "time dependent pie chart". I assume that this exists already, but since I don't know its name I have a hard time googling it.

**Description:**
Let the radius $r$ be the time. Then I get a circle with radius $r$ for every time step. This circle can then be used to represent proportions. By moving out from the middle you could see how the proportions change over time.

Similar but not the same:

- Multilevel pie chart/Sunburst Chart

Comment: Github repo: https://github.com/frnkclsst/d3charts/wiki/donut-charts

Comment: Stack Exchange Post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17507728/d3-js-donut-charts-with-multiple-rings